# Redirect ports with iptables to domain instead of ip

Tags: iptables

Following scenario; I have a homeserver that has a domain with dynamic DNS attached and i want to proxy anyone using my homeserver through a cheap VPS using iptables. The command i tried was:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 30033 -j DNAT -d XXXXXXXXXXXX.myfritz.net:30033
```

but i get

```
iptables v1.6.0: Bad IP address "XXXXXXXXXXXX.myfritz.net"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iptables` can't do that by itself. It only understands IPs, not domains. Here's two ways that you can do what you want:

1. Instead of doing `-j DNAT` to another box, do `-j REDIRECT` and run a userspace program on localhost that handles the DDNS and proxies onward to the real host.
2. Add the rule by IP address, and run a cronjob that checks the DNS for an update, and when it finds one, deletes and re-creates the rule with the new IP.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph Sible, a little off-topic, can you suggest a userspace program that can handle requests with the `-j REDIRECT` option 1?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91711 i ended up creating a bash script for this task (in case you're wondering why a while loop; crontab wouldn't execute it for some reason):

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
while true
do
LOGFILE=/path/to/ip.txt
Current_IP=$(dig +short @YOUR_NAMESERVER YOUR_DYNDNS_DOMAIN)
# Current_IP=$(host $HOSTNAME | head -n1 | cut -f4 -d ' ')
if [ $LOGFILE = "" ] ; then
  iptables -I INPUT -i eth1 -s $Current_IP -j ACCEPT
  echo $Current_IP > $LOGFILE
else
  Old_IP=$(cat $LOGFILE)
  if [ "$Current_IP" = "$Old_IP" ] ; then
    echo "IP address has not changed ($Old_IP -> $Current_IP)"
  else
    iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p udp --dport 9989:10050 -j DNAT --to-destination $Old_IP:9989-10050
    iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 10011 -j DNAT --to-destination $Old_IP:10011
    iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 30033 -j DNAT --to-destination $Old_IP:30033
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 9989:10050 -j DNAT --to-destination $Current_IP:9989-10050
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 10011 -j DNAT --to-destination $Current_IP:10011
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 30033 -j DNAT --to-destination $Current_IP:30033
    sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
    iptables-save
    echo $Current_IP > $LOGFILE
    echo "IP address has changed ($Old_IP -> $Current_IP)"
  fi
fi
sleep 30
done
```

Answer (score 0):

in case someone is still searching for a way to `forward a port to a domain instead of ip so the ip will be resolved from the dns`:

https://github.com/benyamin218118/tcpforwarder

you just need to build or download it and use it like this :

`./tcpforwarder -lPort 8080 -rHost sub.domain.com -rPort 8090`

you can see the example in the documentation